# Add data from list to list in another class conditionally

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a class called WebsiteForm which contains a property `List<Survey>`.

I also have a stored procedure that returns a record set of WebsiteForm data (minus surveys) and a record set of Survey data. These are temporarily stored in lists called formList and surveyList.

I want to be able to put the relevant surveys from surveyList into the survey list in each formList object, if that makes sense. The relevant ones are where the ID property of WebsiteForm matches the LinkID property of Survey.

I imagine this could be done with LINQ but I'm struggling due to the structure of the data.

Thanks.

```
public class WebsiteForm
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<Survey> Surveys { get; set; }
}

public class Survey
{
    public int LinkID { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class CRMService
{
    ...
    public List<WebsiteForm> GetData(string storedProcedure)
    {
        List<WebsiteForm> formList;
        List<Survey> surveyList;

        using (IDbConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            try
            {
                using (var data = sqlConnection.QueryMultiple(storedProcedure, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
                {
                    formList = data.Read<WebsiteForm>().ToList();
                    surveyList = data.Read<Survey>().ToList();

                    // Add surveys from surveyList to each formList item where the LinkID of surveyList matches the ID of formList
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        return formList;
    }
}
```

I'm using Dapper to map the SQL data to the classes btw.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Yeah, I've done that now. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try somthing like this

```
....
formList = data.Read<WebsiteForm>().ToList();
surveyList = data.Read<Survey>().ToList();

formList.ForEach(fl=>fl.Surveys = surveyList.Where(sl=>sl.LinkID == fl.ID).ToList());
....
```